# SharePoint indexing videos in search

Tags: search, crawling, video, refinement-panel

I have created some videos and uploaded them as the video type in the asset library. When I do a search of the content the video type does not appear in the Result type as a video but instead a web page. Is there a way I can make the video type appear as a result type?

**Update**

The refinements web part now has the following added to the refinements xslt:

You can, if you edit the refinements web part Xslt. You can start the exploration here: http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-search-refinement-panel-options/ or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819920.aspx.

```
<CustomFilter CustomValue="Video"> 
    <OriginalValue>wmv</OriginalValue> 
    <OriginalValue>avi</OriginalValue> 
</CustomFilter>
```

I have also made sure that the default box is not selected.

For my search index I have added the file types avi and wmv files. I have performed a full crawl.

In my search center under scopes I am using the all site scope so it should not be excluding the wmv files.

Answer (score 2):

You can, if you edit the refinements web part Xslt. You can start the exploration here: http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-search-refinement-panel-options/ or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819920.aspx.

You need to add something like

```
<CustomFilter CustomValue="Video">
    <OriginalValue>wmv</OriginalValue>
    <OriginalValue>avi</OriginalValue>
</CustomFilter>
```

The webpage CustomFilter contains a default OriginalValue, that must be the reason for what you observe.

Comment: I have done the following but still now joy. Does the content need to be reindexed for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you also need to change the file types which get crawled.

1. Go to the **Search Service Application** within **Central Administration**.
2. In the left navigation section **Crawling**, click **File Types** (this is a list of file type *exclusions*, not inclusions).
3. Make sure the file type you want to crawl is not in this list.
4. Perform a full crawl.

Now the media files should appear within the search results.

Note that avi, mpg, mpeg, and wmv are all **excluded** by default. Meaning they will show up in this list and you need to remove them from this list if you want them to be crawled.

Comment: Sadly no joy. Did a full crawl and they are still not in the result page...

Comment: Is the Asset Library or site searchable? For the library check Library settings > Advanced Settings for the site check Site settings.

Comment: Yep. The display form for the content type Video appear.